# Python JSON parsing problems

Tags: python, json, parsing

Why is this code not working? Please look at this code snippet [Code](https://repl.it/BA4j/2)

i loaded a json string into 'decoded'. Then i tried to access a particular item 'Hausverbrauch' but it doesn't worked.

```
decoded = json.loads(string)
for item in decoded:
    if (item['name'] == 'Hausverbrauch'):
        print item['value']
```

If i print `item['name']` it spits me all the data out.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Amongst other things, you need to be **specific** about what "isn't working" and post the code **here**, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo the Hausvebrauch after item['name'] == so there is no match

Comment: OMG, now i saw it. Thanks!